# Rpm problem VW passat

Tags: vw, passat

2004 VW passat 1.6 petrol  saloon , cant keep rpm constant keeps bouncing up and down about 1 or 2 increments on the rpm gauge only really happens at low rpm not as bad at high rpm and it idles perfect so I'm wondering if it Is the throttle pedal sensor  check engine light is not on either

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the check engine light on the dash?

Comment: No the check engine light is not on

Comment: What do you mean by "...really happens at low rpm not as bad at high rpm" like the rpm bounce while you are driving? What transmission it has? a manual or auto? Is it a new thing with this car? did any maintenance, repair were done recently?

Comment: No it doesnt do it while driving only in neutral and makes it annoying to take off as the rpm is jumping up a down then it's fine once you get going it's a manual but it's not the transmission I'm sure of that and I just bought the car